# How to concentrate lists from a loop into a single lost in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, extract

I need to concentrate some list from a loop. I am using regex to make some extraction, then am using findall in regex which get out all your result on individual list. but i need to get all this list in one. So here is my code..

```
import re
boy = open('mbko.txt')
girl = open ('xxx.txt','w')

for line in boy:
    line = line.rstrip()
    z=  re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9]\S*@\S*[a-zA-Z]',line)

    if len(z)>0:

        leng= len(z)
        girl.write("the total length is :{}\n". format(leng))
        girl.write(str(z))


        print z
```

After this i have the result

```
['stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za']
['postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org']
['source@collab.sakaiproject.org']
['apache@localhost']
['stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za']
```

lol don't mind the naming. but i need to get the list result in one single list like

```
['stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za',
'postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org',
'source@collab.sakaiproject.org',
'apache@localhost',
'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za']
```

i actually added  this part after the `if statement` to get each line join together,

```
final = []
for i in z:
#for j in i:
    final+=i
```

but still can't get a good result.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Looks like python

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a generator:

```
import re

boy = open('mbko.txt')
girl = open('xxx.txt', 'w')

def yielder(boy, girl):

    for line in boy:

        line = line.rstrip()
        z =  re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9]\S*@\S*[a-zA-Z]', line)

        if z:
            girl.write("the total length is :{}\n". format(len(z)))
            girl.write(str(z))

            yield z[0]

print(list(yielder(boy, girl)))
```